# Produce the 95% CI for the expected survival curve of the age-gender-matched general population

Tags: r, survival-analysis, confidence-interval, survival

I have produced the age-gender-matched general population with function survexp() in r. The function detail is as below:

```
survexp(formula, data, weights, subset, na.action, rmap, times,
        method=c("ederer", "hakulinen", "conditional", "individual.h",
                 "individual.s"),
        cohort=TRUE, conditional=FALSE,
        ratetable=survival::survexp.us, scale=1,
        se.fit, model=FALSE, x=FALSE, y=FALSE)
```

I also want to produce the CI for this curve but the argument se.fit=TRUE inside this function is currently ignored. I wonder if there is any other way to produce the CI for the expected survival curve.

I have also produced the expected individual survival rate for each subject. But it seems not helpful for the CI. I also notice some literature mentioning the expected survival curve do not have the 95% CI for them. Because the expected curve is based on the information on the age-gender-matched general population group. We do not have the specific follow up time and status as we have in producing the KM curve. I am curious if producing CI is feasible? Any help is greatly appreciated! Otherwise, if producing the relative survival curve is able to show the great difference between the observed group and the expected group?